# Extraction of Variance Matrices in lmer

Tags: r, matrix, hierarchy, hierarchical-data, lme4

I am trying to extract the **variance components of the random effects from lmer but in a quite specific  and complicated setting**, namely fMRI.

**I will first explain the problem and then provide a reproducible example.**

I am working with **functional fMRI data** and testing aggregation techniques. In this specific context I have 3 Subjects and for every subject there is a matrix containing the first level estimates.
Here every row represents a specific node *i* in the brain and the coefficients are the regression parameter of node*ij* (doesn't matter for the time being how are they calculated or why.
What I am trying to do is to aggregate the results using linear mixed modeling.

Problem is that in lmer working with matrices is, at least from my experience, practically impossible.
So here is what I have done:
First, I created some random matrices and then converted them into vectors

```
   set.seed(49830)
   S.1 <- matrix(rexp(400, rate = 10),20,20)
   S.2 <- matrix(rexp(400, rate = 10),20,20)
   S.3 <- matrix(rexp(400, rate = 10),20,20)

   S1.vec <- as.vector(S.1)
   S2.vec <- as.vector(S.2)
   S3.vec <- as.vector(S.3)
   S.Vec.all <- c(S1.vec, S2.vec, S3.vec)
```

Second, I am creating a fixed effect (let's say the mean activation that is equal for everyone) and the grouping variable. 
In this case I just created a vector centering the data. The code for the *center_scale* function can be found at: http://www.gastonsanchez.com/visually-enforced/how-to/2014/01/15/Center-data-in-R/

```
     constant <- as.vector(center_scale(S.Vec.all)) 
     Group1 <- rep(1, length(S1.vec))
     Group2 <- rep(2, length(S2.vec))
     Group3 <- rep(3, length(S3.vec))
     Group.all <- c(Group1, Group2, Group3)
```

Third, making the dataset, specify the grouping variable as a factor, and running the model.

```
            data.comp <- data.frame(Group.all, constant, S.Vec.all) 
            data.comp$Group.all <- as.factor(data.comp$Group.all)

            mod <- lmer(S.Vec.all ~ constant + (constant|Group.all),
            data = data.comp,
            REML = T,
            control = lmerControl(calc.derivs = FALSE))

            summary(mod)
            ranef(mod)$Group.all
```

Now, problem is that, even if I found a way to extract the random effects and putting them in a matrix format, I still need a way to calculate the variance of these individual matrices for further calculations.

Is there a way to extract the variance of the random coefficients and putting them into a matrix format again?
I found some pseudocode to calculate them, using the formulation by Laird and Ware(1982) which is the one I would like to use, but it still gives me a incredibly big matrix which is totally not understandable to me.
Here is the code:

```
            var.d <- crossprod(getME(mod,'Lambdat'))
            Zt <- getME(mod,"Zt")
            vr <- sigma(mod)^2
            var.b <- vr*(t(Zt) %*% var.d %*% Zt)
            sI <- vr * Diagonal(nrow(data.comp))
            var.y <- var.b + sI
```

I hope that the explanation was clear enough and a huge thanks to all of you who might be able and willing to help me!